# HTML js -Print response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML code and a Javascript. I am trying to make a post to another page and display the responsetext from the other webpage in a alert. But somehow is the success function not displaying the reponsetext from the post for me, can anyone help?

Sorry pretty new to this.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXX" data-callback="sendCaptchaG"></div></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendCaptcha() {
        $(function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
              url: "XXX",
              method: "POST",
              data: {
                'userCode' : "XXX",
                'appVersion' : "100"
              },
              dataType: "html",
              success:function(data) {
              alert(data) },
            });
            grecaptcha.reset();
        });
    }
```

Comment: was there an error message?

Comment: @TobiasK No. The post is ok, but no alert with response

Comment: It looks like sendCaptcha assigns a document.ready handler, rather than doing an ajax request.  You say the post is ok, are you seeing it actually happen in the devtools?

Comment: @James Yes. The post is ok. As soon as I remove the "success function" everything is working great again and the post is ok.